# broken Matlab code for loop no looping

Tags: matlab, loops

I am attempting to solve the n-queen problem for 8 queens. I am having troubles making the first `for` loop repeat itself. It tells me

> Operands to the || and && operators must be convertible to logical scalar values. Error in project_4 (line 12)

`if (ya >= 1)&&(ya <= 8)`

I am unsure what this means or how to fix it. Any suggestions or help would be much appreciated.

```
x1=input('what is the inital x of the queen?');

y1=input('what is the inital y of the queen?');

a1=zeros(8,8);

px=zeros(8);
py=zeros(8);

for k=1:1:8

    for h=1:1:8

        b1=y1-x1;

        ya=h+b1;

        if (ya >= 1)&&(ya <= 8)

            a1(ya,h)=1;

        end
        b2=y1+x1;
        yb=-h+b2;
        if (yb >= 1) && (yb <= 8)
            a1(yb,h)=1;

        end
        a1(y1,h)=1;
        a1(h,x1)=1;
        px(k)=x1;
        py(k)=y1;
    end
    [t,y]=find(a1==0, 1, 'first');
    x1=t;
    y1=y;
end
```

Answer (score 0):

The line `[t,y]=find(a1==0, 1, 'first');` is returning empty values because there are no values for which `a1 == 0`.

Comment: I could have posted this answer

Comment: @Macduff/macduff... Really? =P And both of you are most active in the MATLAB tag...